# How to resample a pandas data indexed by datetime.time (not datetime objects)?

Tags: pandas

Suppose you are looking at something and take

```
df['time'] = df['datetime'].dt.time
```

And you want to resample that? Is there any way to do that conveniently? For example suppose you have extremely sparse observations and you are interested in their daily structure (not datetimely structure).

You can convert everything to ints/hours.

Comment: Maybe `df['time'] = df['datetime'] - df['datetime'].dt.normalize()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang normalize is like dt.round('D') basically. I want to resample on say freq='T' but not on datetimes but on times.